# Manipulating block parameters in Matlab Simulink model with inputs

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

I've created a matlab model with intentions to use it for code generation, specifically with the PLC coder.  The model is basically the example discrete PID block with the error calculation included, but additionally I want the gains and sample time to be inputs.  This may not make sense in Simulink, but for generated PLC code it is a preferred solution.

Currently I have the variables for the gain blocks (Kp, Ki, Kd) in the model workspace as double's with dimensions [1 1], and then I use the 'ToWorkspace' blocks from the inputs.  This does not work in simulation, it seems to only use the initial values no matter what.

The 'SampleTime' variable has no effect either.  This variable is used for the 'SampeTime' parameter in both the Integrator and Filter blocks.  This is a must because in the PLC generated code I pass the cycle time of the processor to the function so it integrates properly as the scan time can vary.

Additionally, the PLC code generator works fine, however, the gains, integrators, filter, SampleTime, do not show up in the code at all.  All I really get are two sum functions.

Any idea how I should approach this?  I can replace the gain blocks with product blocks but it doesn't help me on the sample time issue.  Thanks.

[image: DiscretePID]

Comment: What do you mean "has no effect"? On what? Also, teh "to workspace" block has no meaning in the PLC, as the PLC will not be running MATLAB, but an executable of the simulink blocks. Thus there is no such thing as "workspace" when the code runs in the PLC, I guess.

Comment: You cannot change mask/dialog values using values from input signals.

Comment: @Ander, when I run simulation with the block with different values for the Kp, Ki, Kd, CyclTime variables, nothing changes.  Also, I understand there is no 'to workspace' in the PLC, however, I hoped that Matlab would change the workspace scope to the function block scope in the generator.  It certainly cannot exist out of scope of the block in the plc.

Comment: @Navan, are you suggesting there's no way to alter a block's parameter from outside the Block Parameters dialog?

Comment: As far as I know the "to workspace" block is not an scope. It will store all values, and when the simulation ends, it will return the values to workspace. if you are doing PLC coding, your "simulation" never ends. How do you set up the different values of Kp,Ki,Kd? As far as we know your system can be so stable that it always work. You show a PID controller, but we have no idea what are you controlling. You are debugging this setting the inputs yourself and measuring the uotput with an oscilloscope, right?  Also, do not hope that anything happens, make it happen!

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I didn't understand that the 'ToWorkspace' block only worked at the end of the simulation.  Regrading what I'm controlling, it's nothing in this case, this model is just to test the PLC coder.   Let's forget the PLC coder all-together, is it possible to modify block parameters with an input?  Sounds like no.

Comment: What is "block parameters"? The gain Kp? If you replace it by a multiplication by the input, then yes, yes you can.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I knew replacing it with multiplication would work, but there are other block types that can't be swapped 1:1 for a simple mathematics block.  The discreet integrator blocks will not work then, as I cannot set the 'SampleTime' from an input?

Comment: The discrete integration blocks can be rewriten with simple mathematics blocks. The equation is essentially printed on the block in the image you posted. I assume you need the sample time for this, or do you need it for something else also? Just so you know: almost every block that does maths can be rewritten with simple mathematical blocs, because well, that is how they were written in the first place!